# How to get value of my array in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

Here is my code getting jsonp request .

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: pbxApi+"/confbridge_participants/conference_participants.json?cid="+circle,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: 'callback',
        contentType: "application/javascript",
        success: function(data) {

         console.log(data);

        }
        });
```

and here is the request

[image]

it outputs all the data in the array.

I want to output specific value only

like value of the uid.

i want output uid for each object returned. how will i do it?

Comment: do you want to output the uid for each object returned or for only a specified one?

Comment: i want output uid for each object returned. how will i do it?

Comment: use `jQuery.each(data, function(index, item) {
              console.log(item.uid);
        });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/), as this function will iterate `data` variable :

```
 $.each(data, function(i,e){
   // do something here 
   console.log(e.id);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you are looking to do is to print the uid of each object you can iterate over the array of objects and access each uid individually

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: pbxApi+"/confbridge_participants/conference_participants.json?cid="+circle,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: 'callback',
    contentType: "application/javascript",
    success: function(data) {
        for( var obj in data ) {
            // Accessing object property using dot notation
            console.log(obj.uid);
            // Or square bracket notation
            console.log(obj['uid']);
        }
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to return a new modified version of the array;

```
console.log(data.map(function(o) { return o.id; }));
```